# Flow of server path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I just started reading Web Development with Node and Express and have come across a question not answered in the book. They give a basic layout that allows a server request to `home`, `/about`, and `/404`. Each one has it's own HTML file with an image within.

Here is the code they give:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode){
    if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
            res.end('500 - Internal Error');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(responseCode, {'Content-Type':contentType});
            res.end(data);
        }
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    //normalize url by removing querystring, optional
    //trailing slash, and making it lowercase
    var path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/,'').toLowerCase();
    switch(path){
        case '':
            console.log('1');
            serveStaticFile(res, '/public/home.html', 'text/html');
            break;
        case '/about':
            console.log('2');
            serveStaticFile(res, '/public/about.html', 'text/html');
            break;
        case '/img/error.jpeg':
            console.log('3');
            serveStaticFile(res, '/public/img/error.jpeg', 'image/jpeg');
            break;
        case '/img/logo.jpeg':
            console.log('4');
            serveStaticFile(res, '/public/img/logo.jpeg', 'image/jpeg');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('5');
            serveStaticFile(res, '/public/404.html', 'text/html');
            break;
    }
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server started on localhost:8080');
```

Each HTML file for `home`, `about`, and `404` has its own `<img>` tag, so I thought the image would be automatically rendered when a user requests a url. How come we need extra cases in the `switch` to handle the images? For example, if I type in `http://localhost:8080/about`, it logs `2` then `4`. Why does the case for `about` also call the case for `'/img/logo.jpeg'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because images are requested separately from html, js files, css files by the browser.

Each static resource is fetched by browser in a separate http request. If an html page needs 5 javascript files, 3 css files, 4 images the browser will make 5+3+4+1 = 13 requests.

Answer (score 1):

The `'/about'` case logs 2 and renders the static file `'/public/about.html'`. I bet that the `'/public/about.html'` page includes an image tag like `<img src="/public/img/logo.jpeg">`. That will hit the server with the url `'/public/img/logo.jpeg'`, and log 4.

So your case statement is breaking properly; it's just that you're probably making two requests to the server: one for the about page, and one for the logo image.

Answer (score 1):

I've read this book as well.  The code you're referring to is in chapter 2 and is more of an example of a clunky way to do routing.  In the next chapter the author goes on to discuss how Express makes routing easy.

To answer your question, you don't need routes in a switch statement, or an API for that matter, for serving images.  As long as the paths are in the HTML that's returned or built on the client side, images will download automatically.

Comment: Yup, I'm on to chapter 3, I just wanted to understand the basics before I moved on